# Integer solutions to a logarithmic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

What are the solutions to the equation: $$\log_{3}\left(2^{x}+1\right) = y$$ where $x,y$ are integers. The first few are $x=1,3$. How would I prove that there are either finite or infinite solutions?

Comment: What is the equation?

Comment: cf. [Mihailescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides#Works_in_mathematics_and_astronomy/astrology)

Comment: Note it is dupe because one can easily show (considering \mod 9 and \mod 8) that for non-trivial solutions, we need to solve $9^y - 8^x = 1$.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Mihailescu's Theorem is the answer